# Warning: Expression Result Unused in RenderScript

Tags: c, c99, renderscript

I don't get it. Unless I'm missing something, I use it on the next line.

```
blockAverage >> blockSize; //Warning:expression result unused
return rsPackColorTo8888(blockAverage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant:

```
blockAverage >>= blockSize;
```

Your code doesn't change `blockAverage`; you just compute the value of `blockAverage` shifted right by  `blockSize` bits, then throw the result away.

You must use assignment to *change* the value of a variable (the above is, of course, short for `blockAverage = blockAverage >> blockSize;` i.e. it clearly assigns a new value to `blockAverage`).

Comment: Is this an objective C thing? I don't recall x >> y ever being a problem when I was working with Microcontrollers.

Comment: @JohnMoffitt Your recollection must be a bit shady. You realize that `>>` ist just like any other binary operator; would you expect `int a = 3, b = 4; a + b;` to make `a` equal 7, too?

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is bit-wise right shift operator. You need to assign the value of the expression `blockAverage >> blockSize;`. You can modify `blockAverage` by either

```
blockAverage = blockAverage >> blockSize;
```

or

```
blockAverage >>= blockSize;
```